# String comparison in Arduino

Tags: arduino, arduino-c++

This code asks the user for a colour (red,green or yellow) and turns the LED on.
However for some reason, it doesn't work. All the confitions turn out to be false even when i put the correct values (red ,yellow or green)
I don't know what the reason is for this code to not work...

```
enter code here
 
void loop() {
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
Serial.println(Msg1);
while(Serial.available()==0){}
Val=Serial.readString();

if (Val=="red") {
  digitalWrite(redLed,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(yLed,LOW);
} else if (Val=="green"){
  digitalWrite(redLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(yLed,LOW);
} else if (Val=="yellow") {
  digitalWrite(redLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(greenLed,LOW);
  digitalWrite(yLed,HIGH);
}  

 }
```

Comment: where is the problem? Is Serial.print(Val); printing the correct value?

Comment: Does `readString` get rid of the line endings?  (CR and/or LF?) They might be tagging along at the end of the string after the "red", for example.

Comment: The problem is that all the conditions in the if statement turn out to be false even when i give the correct val(red or yellow or green)

Comment: Yes Serial.print(val) does give the correct value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Val.trim() after readString will remove whitespace and your program will run as expected.

Comment: You are welcome, and invited to mark the answer so the post will show as answered.